# Artwork for the site

Tags: discussion, design

Different SE sites have site specific artwork (love the one on [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/))..
So my question is who will make one for chem.SE ... the chem.SE users or someone from stack exchange??

Comment: We don't need to worry about it much yet. Of course, feel free to come up with your own designs, Jin may use 'em :)

Answer (score 2):

The design of the graduated SE sites is done mostly by Jin and some sites by Sean Gallagher, both are SE employees. They sometimes hire external artists and designers for the design.

The users can give some input on the design, but it is finally created by SE.

Comment: True, but there is no reason to preempt users trying to give ideas for this or that aspect.  They usually solicit ideas before they begin in earnest, and if people are able to come up with ideas for a longer period then all the better.

Comment: @NickT is correct.  Check out this meta post: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/493/can-site-users-suggest-some-design-specifications-regarding-graduated-site-devel

Answer (score 2):

An idea for the voting arrows...

[image: I guess this is a triplet state]

Comment: No, they should be single-barb curved arrows!

Comment: are you sure Jim will look here if we make suggestions?

Comment: @Manishearth - How about coordinate covalent bonds?

Comment: @Ashu - I have no idea :D

Comment: But it looks so.. so... academically black and white!  I think I'm reading another journal article with those arrows! :(